# Как в listView, в каждой item, дать кнопке ID из уникального номера телефона?

Tags: java, android, listview

В list_item.xml одна кнопка на item, у кнопки android:id="@+id/btn"

В классе `private class ButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener`

Нахожу её

```
RelativeLayout ve = (RelativeLayout)v.getParent();

TextView btn = (TextView) ve.findViewById(R.id.btn);
```

Делаю

```
btn.getId();
```

Дает для каждой кнопки id 2131361941

.setId() предлагает задать id из ресурсов, но мои номера id приходят с сервера, поэтому не вариант.

Короч, я просто хочу дать каждой кнопке в своей item свой id состоящий из номера телефона, для того чтоб потом обращаться к этой кнопке и менять в ней текст, как это сделать?

Comment: ListView не создает отдельный View для каждого элемента списак, поэтому сделать так, как вы хотите не получится.

Comment: Короч, пришол к выводы что лучше по кликлистенер с каждой кнопкой её .getTag передовать.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве setId() можно задать любое число типа `int`, но в данном случае это сомнительное решение. Возможно лучше воспользоваться `setTag()`

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вам нужно создать ArrayList и в CustomArrayAdapter отлавливать нажатие на ваш TextView соответственно position и получать данные с Item